# Rails Advanced Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got three models called `User`, `Account` and `AccountPermission`.

I established associations between `User` and `Account` through `AccountPermission` so, It's `has_many :through`

I also established `User` and `Account` with `has_many` via **creator_id**. Because, I need to know the creator of accounts.

I'm creating `Account` and `User` same time with nested attributes. However, I also want to add a **creator_id** to my `User` in same transaction.

Do you have any idea for this case ?

Here is my associations,

[image: associations]

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_many :created, class_name: 'Account', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'

     has_many :account_permissions, :class_name => 'AccountPermission'
     has_many :accounts, through: :account_permissions

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_permissions
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'

    has_many :accounts_permissions, :class_name => 'AccountPermission'
    has_many :users, through: :accounts_permissions
```

**account_permission.rb**

```
class AccountPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :account

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
```

**controller#new**

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.account_permissions.build.build_account
    respond_with(@user)
 end
```

My SQL,

```
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (12.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "country") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "testemail@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$2XeCSewQ3JqIFNjwktfQZ.nt/.iWsT7ea6SSmVrrzWAcqHqMuubUy"], ["first_name", "test name"], ["last_name", "test lastname"], ["created_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC], ["country", "EC"]]


  SQL (4.4ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "testsubdomain"], ["created_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC]]


  SQL (6.4ms)  INSERT INTO "account_permissions" ("user_id", "account_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 51], ["account_id", 19], ["created_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-09 11:15:46 UTC]]


  (1.9ms)  COMMIT
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to add creator_id to account table in same transaction automatically. If you look at insert sql, in second one, system is adding name attribute to account. It should also add creator_id. By the way, I'm using devise controller.

Comment: @utkuDAT I think you want to rename it user_id not creater_id. It is rails convention that to use a foreign key to refer to another table that it is the table name [user] and then adding _id on the end. it helps with things like has_many or belongs_to to know what is connected. Are you having these accounts be tied to things like Oauth2? or just separating them in general?

Comment: you need to set creator_id when you create the account. IE: edited_user.accounts.create(creator_id: logged_user)

Comment: Actually i set a foreign key in my user.rb you can see. I called that relation as 'created' so when i run user.created, it'll give me account that created by this user.  But if i run user.accounts it'll give me accounts which is accessble by user. And the end, i can Manage users and accounts even creators

Comment: @ThomasSevestre yes i can do something like that. I could update creator id after all of them is done. But i don't want to do it with a different transaction. I guess i should handle it in my New action that shared above